# Margin-bottom not being applied to some images

Tags: html, css

I am adding a very small amount of margin-bottom on my images. However, the margin is not applied to some images for some strange reason. If the margin-bottom is not applied you will see no white space between the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/9s4031Lk

Edit: It seems that the margin is added to every image when I run the code in stackoverflow. But the margin is not added to every image in my local dev environment and on jsfiddle.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.05rem;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516733968668-dbdce39c4651?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516733968668-dbdce39c4651?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516733968668-dbdce39c4651?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516733968668-dbdce39c4651?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516733968668-dbdce39c4651?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516733968668-dbdce39c4651?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516733968668-dbdce39c4651?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516733968668-dbdce39c4651?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516733968668-dbdce39c4651?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
```

Comment: Hi the margin is added in both stack overflow as well as your jsfiddle.

Comment: in the jsfiddle, there are some images with no margin. in this picture you see it has no white space. https://imgur.com/a/unRMXix

Comment: I see a margin on every picture on my end.  Your margin is very very small to begin with.  Maybe increase it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your padding is `0.05rem` which translates to 0.8 pixels in most browsers. What you're seeing is the browser rounding the value (sometimes up and sometimes down).

Use a minimum of `0.0625rem` instead to always get padding (at least when the default browser text size is 16px or higher).